# QApplication: invalid style override 'kvantum' passed, ignoring it

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pipenv

I'm trying to read an image from bytes with **Python**. I'm using the **open-cv** library with **pipenv** on **Manjaro**. When python runs this line, I get:

> QApplication: invalid style override 'kvantum' passed, ignoring it. Available styles: Windows, Fusion".

Do you have any ideas what might cause this issue and how to fix it ?
The thing is, I don't think I can change the theme through the library.

Thank you !

That's my code

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(img_data, dtype=np.uint8), flags=0)
```

Comment: please retag. your error relates to Qt, not opencv

Comment: Sure. Yet, maybe there's a way to bypass when using python. But I edited it.

Comment: what precisely did you find when you searched online for your error message, or parts of it?